# Rechts vs. nach rechts

Tags: word-usage, usage

After a bit of searching, I haven't found a clear difference between "rechts" and "nach rechts".

First of all, do they have the same meaning?

Second, are there situations in which one is clearly used instead of the other?

Comment: I will think about this more but for now.. "nach rechts" is a direction like in turn right when driving a car. While "rechts" in this example 'stay on the right [side]' is different. It is difficult to distinguish. But imagine "nach rechts" as if you would change your location or moving towards there. Tho both of them are basically meaning the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They don't mean the same, they are different. It's rather simple:

- ***rechts*** is a place
- ***nach rechts*** is a direction

---

### Wo? - Rechts

Two persons watch a big old painting in an art gallery.

> Woman:
>   Oh, dieser kleine Hund ist so süß.
>   Oh, this little dog is so sweet.
>
> Man:
>   **Wo** siehst du einen Hund in diesem Bild?
>   **Where** do you see a dog in this picture?
>
> Woman:
>   **Rechts** unten.
>   At the **right** bottom corner (Literally just: "**right** bottom")

---

### Wohin? - Nach rechts.

Two persons drive through an unknown city, the passenger reads the map.

> driver:
>   **Wohin** müssen wir bei der nächsten Kreuzung?
>   **Where (to)** do we have to go at the next junction?
>
> passenger:
>   **Nach rechts**
>   **To the right**

---

In both of the examples given above you have no choice. When asked for the place of the dog, you can't answer "nach rechts". You have to say "rechts". But when asked for the next direction to turn, then "rechts" would be wrong. It must be "nach rechts".

Both German words, "wo" and "wohin" can be translated as "where" in Englisch, which makes it hard to decide which one to use in German if you are an English native speaker. But sometimes you can use "where **to**" instead of simple "where", and when ever you can add this "*to*", then you are asking for a direction, not for a place. And in this case you have to add "nach" in German.

Comment: In the situation in the car above I could easyly imagine the passenger saying (or shouting ;) ) "Hier rechts" without the "nach".

Comment: @Beta: Im Ernst? »Wohin müssen wir bei der nächsten Kreuzung?« - »*Hier* rechts« statt »*Nach* rechts«? Würdest du das nur direkt bei der Kreuzung sagen, oder auch z.B. 200 m vor der nächsten Kreuzung? Und warum ist *schreien* (*shouting*) eine Option für dich? Der Beifahrer, der die Karte liest und dem Fahrer den Weg ansagt, sitzt ja direkt neben dem Fahrer, also durchaus in bester Hörweite.

Comment: @Beta: Gehört nicht zu dieser Frage, aber ich weiß nicht, wie ich dich sonst kontaktieren kann: In deinem Profil steht »...  in Schweden. Zweisprachig oder eher anderthalbsprachig aufgewachsen.« Welches sind deine beiden Muttersprachen? Deutsch und Schwedisch? Welche davon ist die ganze, welche die halbe?

Comment: Ich meine ganz vor der Kreuzung wenn der Autofahrer fast vorbeifährt ohne jede Zeichen zu zeigen, dass er ablenken will. Könnte leicht einen Schrei auslösen. Daher hab ich " ;) " geschrieben. Tatsäcklich ist das als Fahrer Selbsterlebt. Wenn es um meine Muttersprache geht ist das ja Schwedisch, wiel ich heir aufgewachsen bin. Mein Deutsch könnte wirklich wesentlich verbessert werden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Super Antwort - ich verstehe allerdings nicht so ganz was die Antworten auf Betas Scherz bewirken sollen... Sein Kommentar war schließlich problemlos als solcher zu erkennen. Auch die Nachfrage nach der Muttersprache halte ich in diesem Kontext für unnötig. Mich würde interessieren was der Grund dafür ist?

Comment: @Joshit Ich würde von schlichter Neugierde bei der Muttersprachenfrage ausgehen ;)

Comment: @Joshit: Den Scherz habe ich nicht als solchen erkannt. Ich schaue von allen Leute, die hier etwas posten, die Profile an, weil ich wissen will, mit wem ich es zu tun habe. (Aus genau diesem Grund gibt es Profile.) Gerade die Frage, ob jemand Deutsch als Muttersprache spricht, halte ich hier in einem Deutsch-Forum für sehr wichtig. Es hat aber wenig Sinn, in einem Profil anzugeben wieviele Sprachen man spricht, wenn dann erst wieder niemand weiß welche das sind. Daher habe ich nachgefragt.

Comment: OK. Danke für die Aufklärung

Comment: @Beta: Danke für dein verbessertes Profil! Kleine Korrektur: Entweder: »... mir ist aber in Kindheit auch etwas Deutsch beigebracht **worden**.« Oder: »... mir **wurde** aber in Kindheit auch etwas Deutsch beigebracht.«

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context.

"rechts" basically means the opposite of left and is the exact translation of "right". Usually you ask with "**wo**":

> Wo steht das Buch (rechts oder links)?
>
> *Rechts.*

It's not a about a direction, it's rather about a side or a place.

"nach rechts" is usually used in context of ways and direction. It's rather translated with "to the right". You ask with "**wohin**".

> Wohin müssen wir abiegen? / Wohin hast du das Buch gestellt?
>
> *Nach rechts*.

Comment: Hm, du hast recht. Hab jetzt nochmal nachgedacht, es macht wirklich keinen Sinn ^^. Sorry dafür. Die Grundaussage von meiner Antwort ist aber dennoch richtig.